# If $\mathrm{tr}(x) = \mathrm{tr}(x^3)$ for every $x \in k$, does it imply $p=3$?

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $k \supset \Bbb F_p$ be a finite field where $p \geq 3$, and let $\mathrm{tr} : k \to \Bbb F_p$ be the trace map.
Assume that
$$\forall x \in k,    \mathrm{tr}(x) = \mathrm{tr}(x^3)$$

Does it imply that $p=3$? This is of course a sufficient condition, but is it necessary? It seems to be so, on some examples (note that $p=2$ is not allowed to exclude the case $k = \Bbb F_2$).

If $n = [k : \Bbb F_p]$ is not divisible by $p$, this is true since by letting $x=2 \in \Bbb F_p$ we get $2n = 8n \in \Bbb F_p$ so $p \mid 6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $a\in k$, $Y^3-Y-a$ has at most 3 roots in $k$ so the image of $f:k\to k, f(x)=x^3-x$ has at least $\frac{|k|}3$ elements.

On other hand, from that $tr$ is surjective $k\to \Bbb{F}_p$ we know that $\ker tr$  has $\frac{|k|}p$ elements.

$f(k)\subset \ker tr$ gives $$\frac{|k|}3\le |f(k)|\le |\ker tr|= \frac{|k|}p$$ so that $p\le 3$.